# How to tweet multiple images using twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

I post one image ,but with multiple i have problem.

[image]
[image]

```
public function sendMediaTweet($access_token, $access_token_secret, $media,$status)
{
    $media_ids_str = implode(',', $media);
    var_dump($media_ids_str);
    Twitter::reconfig(['token' => $access_token,
        'secret' => $access_token_secret]);

    $media1 = Twitter::uploadMedia(['media_data' => $media_ids_str]);
    $parameters = ['status' => $status,'media_ids' => $media1->media_id_string];
    Twitter::postTweet($parameters);
}
```

Comment: What sort of problem? Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: With this code I can send one photo and any text to one post, and I need to send some images and text to one post.